# Remover marcas padrão do mapa no android

Tags: android, google-maps

Não testei, mas aparentemente no javaScript dá para remover as marcas padrão do mapa usando MapTypeStyleFeatureType - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538444/how-do-i-remove-default-markers.

Qual é a classe relacionada na API do android?

***Se conseguir diminuir o tamanho do texto já estaria bom.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para remover os marcadores que são adicionados no [Google Place](https://developers.google.com/places/?hl=pt-br) por [addMarker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions%29), que neste caso usaria `googleMap.addMarker()` você pode fazer assim:

```
marker.remove()
```

O método addMarker é:

```
public final Marker addMarker (MarkerOptions options)
```

E para limpar todos 'scribbles' do mapa basta você chamar o [`clear()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#clear()) como mostra abaixo:

```
map.clear();
```

Comment: Como faço para obter a referência das marcas adicionada por padrão? As marcas que adicionei com addMarker tranquilo.

Comment: @EdsonFSantos Você já tentou usar o `clear`.

Comment: Acabei de testar, o clear remove as marcas que adicionei com addMarker

Comment: Não é possível remover essas marcas pela Google API, porém já foi feito um apelo junto a Google por parte dos desenvolvedores, conforme o link: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841

Comment: As remoção das marcas agora está disponível veja documentação em https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features e o editor de estilos em https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/